# Bootstrap two anchor tag side by side in one control group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two anchor tags side by side in a control group. I am using twitter bootstrap for this project. But these two anchor tags always overlap each other

My html is as below

```
<div class="control-group">
     <div class="controls">
          <a id="address" class=" pull-right update btn btn-inverse btn-medium push-top">Update</a>
          <a class="pull-right delete_add btn btn-inverse btn-medium push-top">Delete</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What does push-top do? Works fine here so something else must be affecting it? http://jsfiddle.net/ZaMZ8/

Comment: it does a margin-top:15px

Comment: Use Firebug to inspect the elements and see what CSS rules are present that you aren't expecting to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is the `pull-right`-class. This class floats the two inline-boxes to the right.

You can solve the problem by adding a new class for aligning text elements to your CSS:

```
.align-right{
   text-align: right;
}
```

In your HTML-Code remove the `pull-right`-class and add `align-right` to your `controls` group.

```
<div class="control-group">
     <div class="controls align-right">
          <a id="address" class="update btn btn-inverse btn-medium push-top">Update</a> 
          <a class="delete_add btn btn-inverse btn-medium push-top">Delete</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/FZZsu/